# Entity Framework 6.0.1 needlessly casting smallint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Anyone know why EF6 would be needlessly re-casting an Int16 to smallint?  Using the logging function, I see it performed the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[LabelName] AS [LabelName], Project1.Usage, Project1.FacilityID
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[LabelName] AS [LabelName], 
        [Extent1].[Usage] AS [Usage],
        extent1.facilityid
        FROM [dbo].[Label] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[DeleteInd]) 
        AND ([Extent1].[FacilityID] IN (cast(1 as smallint), cast(5 as smallint))) 
        AND (([Extent1].[LabelName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~') OR ([Extent1].[LabelName] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE '~'))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Usage] DESC
-- p__linq__0: '%test%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
-- p__linq__1: 'test%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
-- Executing at 12/6/2013 4:08:49 PM -08:00
-- Completed in 16 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

This is the Linq query:

```
Context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
var labels = (from label in Context.Labels
                where label.DeleteInd == false &&
                Settings.FacilitySearch.Contains(label.Facility.FacilityID)  &&
                (label.LabelName.Contains(searchText) || label.LabelName.StartsWith(searchText))
                orderby label.Usage descending
                select label.LabelName);

return labels.ToList();
```

EF knows the FacilityId is smallint <-> Int16 (would show a picture but not enough reputation points :-/)

project:
C# WinForms .NET 4.0
Windows 7 SP1
Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Try using `DataAnnotation` above the property, something like: `[Column(TypeName = "INT")]` (example)

Comment: What's the type of `Settings.FacilitySearch`?

Comment: @Tico: why would this be required when the EF mapping already knows its an INT16?  I'm using database first development.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: It's a: 
`ReadOnlyCollection<Int16> FacilitySearch`

Comment: @BSOD2600 I understand your point. But what Code First does is just create the DB for you. Unless you have knowledge of what's going on behind the scenes, force somethings. I'm not a good programmer, but I'll assume that the cast is made to make the DB smaller and so. But I've been using CF and I never seen this. weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this conversion isn't required in this particular case, but it was simpler to write code that always performs casts, and assume that SQL Server will probably optimize it out anyway. The developers probably figured it's better to generate needlessly complex SQL than to maintain needlessly complex code.

Comment: yea I can see the logic in that.  Agreed, better than sprinkling database specific annotations in the code and let the EF/SQL handle the optimizations.

Comment: Sadly that assumption is bad as this results in some seriously bad execution times. I am stuck by that one too now.

Comment: Sadly that assumption is bad as this results in some seriously bad execution times. I am stuck by that one too now. As you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149456/entity-framework-ridiculous-query-casting-smallint-to-int-for-comparison that takes the execution from hardly measureable to 5 minutes as it creates a self join in the execution plan.